# Instruments crashed on startup - Appium ios real device

Tags: appium

### I am doing iOS automation on real device. But i got stuck with the error "Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup". logs are below. Please help to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

```
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Desktop/PlainNote/code/sencha/cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator/Fly_dotREZ.ipa","platformVersion":"7.1.2","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 5S","bundleId":"com.accenture.london.Voyage-Air","udid":"5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)
info: [debug] Using local .ipa from desired caps: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Desktop/PlainNote/code/sencha/cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator/Fly_dotREZ.ipa
info: [debug] Copying local zip to tmp dir
info: [debug] /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Desktop/PlainNote/code/sencha/cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator/Fly_dotREZ.ipa copied to /var/folders/mt/7w1_nx811y9cyx1778lqs_700000gq/T/115210-67883-1h28vtl/appium-app.zip
info: [debug] Unzipping /var/folders/mt/7w1_nx811y9cyx1778lqs_700000gq/T/115210-67883-1h28vtl/appium-app.zip
info: [debug] Testing zip archive: /var/folders/mt/7w1_nx811y9cyx1778lqs_700000gq/T/115210-67883-1h28vtl/appium-app.zip
info: [debug] Zip archive tested clean
info: [debug] Unzip successful
info: [debug] Using locally extracted app: /var/folders/mt/7w1_nx811y9cyx1778lqs_700000gq/T/115210-67883-1h28vtl/Payload/Fly dotREZ.app
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 709e3337-b330-4549-b6d0-eb10722cc83b
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
info: [debug] Setting Xcode version
info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout
info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 7.0
info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
info: [debug] Parsed app Localizable.strings
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. D...ot manually modify!
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b98646d39f6b505e.js
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b98646d39f6b505e.js
info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set
info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator
info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095
info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095 --bundle com.accenture.london.Voyage-Air
info: [debug] App is installed.
info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
info: [debug] Starting command proxy.
info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Starting instruments
info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095 com.accenture.london.Voyage-Air -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b98646d39f6b505e.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-10 17:30:06.747 instruments[67920:707] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'jitendra.k.dash’s iPhone (v7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-10 17:30:06.862 instruments[67920:2203] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'jitendra.k.dash’s iPhone (v7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095 com.accenture.london.Voyage-Air -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b98646d39f6b505e.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-10 17:30:13.444 instruments[67923:707] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'jitendra.k.dash’s iPhone (v7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-10 17:30:13.555 instruments[67923:2003] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'jitendra.k.dash’s iPhone (v7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #2
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095 com.accenture.london.Voyage-Air -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b98646d39f6b505e.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-10 17:30:20.152 instruments[67927:707] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'jitendra.k.dash’s iPhone (v7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-10 17:30:20.253 instruments[67927:3f03] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'jitendra.k.dash’s iPhone (v7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #3
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5f5e07c61ae3ad4f755801bd6336d21d90927095 com.accenture.london.Voyage-Air -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b98646d39f6b505e.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-10 17:30:26.840 instruments[67930:707] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'jitendra.k.dash’s iPhone (v7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-10 17:30:26.952 instruments[67930:3827] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'jitendra.k.dash’s iPhone (v7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:389:31)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 24889.612 ms - 182
```

Comment: You should make sure you can launch the app using Instruments manually.

Comment: is this solved until today or maybe you can try looking for these : 1. Are you able to access the instruments in ways other than appium script? 2. Also please make sure you have Use Native Instruments Library checked under Advance settings for IOS platform in Appium's UI. 3. Enable UI Automation setting in setting--developer

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I  did not have the appium instruments node package installed. Once I installed it the crash went away. Check that you have the appium-instruments node package installed:

```
    npm install appium-instruments
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to keep in mind while running in real device:
1)No simulator should be opened.
2)Make sure the .app file which you are using is build for real device(take the help of developer to find it out)
3)Pass correct udid and bundle id.
4)If you are getting error like app installed failed or something like that then try to do pass app path from appium gui and other parameters from your code i.e. device name , platform capabilities; trying these different combinations do help sometimes.